# How can you programmatically enable & disable the Java Runtime Engine on Windows?

Tags: powershell, java

I try to keep the Java Runtime Environment from being enabled in an effort to help protect my computer from malware that attempts to load via a Java applet. Every now and then, typically when using remote meeting software or the like, I need to temporarily enable Java.

Typically, this involves opening Control Panel, running the Java Control Panel, selecting the Java tab, clicking View and either checking or unchecking the "Enabled" checkbox for the version of Java that's installed on my Windows 7 system.

I'd like to write either a couple of batch scripts or a powershell commandlet or  so that I can save myself a bunch of clicks when I want to toggle Java on when I need it enabled, and then to run another script to toggle it back off again when I'm done.

What is the checking and unchecking process modifying when I'm doing this? A registry entry?

Comment: Yea these settings are stored in the registry. JRE updates may revert these to their defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only concerned about applets, simply disable/enabled Java in the browser. They can't be started from other programs anyway.

For Firefox you can use an extension like NoScript of PrefBar to make this easier.

Comment: +1: NoScript is a better option as it remember which web sites you want to enable Java or JavaScript for. I suspect malware in Java is pretty rare, but the ability to block ads can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nifty program called regshot that will help you out here and also for other things in the future where you need to identify registry setting locations for programs.

http://code.google.com/p/regshot/

You run the program and create a snapshot of your registry, then make the software setting change and create the second snapshot and then compare. It will show you all the keys that have changed. You will be interested in the keys under the Java registry path.

To set registry key values with PowerShell you use the `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Java\Subkey -Name RegValueNameHere -Value YourValue
```

Answer (score 0):

After tracking down all occurrences of the java.exe file, you could simply rename it when not in use.